# Pass an arbitrary image size to cnn in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a lenet model in pytorch, The ideia is to put images of any size in it, so I started doing with `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d` but the error comes as

> mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0

Here is my code

```
class LeNet5(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
    super(LeNet5, self).__init__()

    self.conv_1 = nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, bias=False
    )
    self.relu_1 = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.maxpool_1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    self.conv_2 = nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels=32, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, bias=False
    )
    self.relu_2 = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.maxpool_2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
    self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=120, bias=False)
    self.fc_2 = nn.Linear(in_features=120, out_features=84)
    self.fc_3 = nn.Linear(in_features=84, out_features=num_classes)

  def forward(self, input):
    conv_1_output = self.conv_1(input)
    relu_1_output = self.relu_1(conv_1_output)
    maxpool_1_output = self.maxpool_1(relu_1_output)
    conv_2_output = self.conv_2(maxpool_1_output)
    relu_2_output = self.relu_2(conv_2_output)
    maxpool_2_output = self.maxpool_2(relu_2_output)
    flatten_output = self.flatten((self.avgpool(maxpool_2_output).view(maxpool_2_output.shape[0], -1)))
    fc_1_output = self.fc_1(flatten_output)
    fc_2_output = self.fc_2(fc_1_output)
    fc_3_output = self.fc_3(fc_2_output)

    return fc_3_output
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your code but try swapping: `.view(maxpool_2_output.shape[0], -1)))` to `.view(-1, maxpool_2_output.shape[0])))`.

Comment: I tried and it gives **stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1, 23, 23] at entry 0 and [1, 37, 37] at entry 1**

Comment: i have posted the answer, it will work

Comment: I got it! It was related to the number of batches, for this case of variable sized image it has to be `numb_batch = 1` and I was using `numb_batch = 64`.

Comment: no batch size doesnt matter

Answer (score 1):

if you read the theory on **AdaptiveAvgPool2d**, this is what it says " we specify the output size And the stride and kernel-size are automatically selected to adapt to the needs"
More info available [here](https://forums.fast.ai/t/ideas-behind-adaptive-max-pooling/12634/4)
Hence Your spatial dimension is reduced by `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` and not the depth of feature maps.
So, the spatial dimension will be `1x1` and depth will still be `256` , making your
`self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=120, bias=False)` and not `self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=120, bias=False)`

Comment: I had to take this in account too, with 4096 didn't work, but with 256 it did.